# plotly barplot with two y axis aligned at zero

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have a simple data set and  want to create a bar plot with two y-axis. I use the following code:

```
data = {'col 1': [-6, 18.6, 106.35, 111],
        'col 2': [-787.5, 976.5, 11246, 25682]}
df_overview = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_overview.index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
colors = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF']  # red, blue
columns = ['col 1', 'col 2']
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=df_overview.index, y=df_overview[col], name=col, marker_color=colors[i], offsetgroup=i,),
        secondary_y=(i == 0)
    )
fig.update_layout(
    barmode='group',
    font_size=14,
    hovermode="x unified",
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

But somehow, both y-axis do not align at zero. Is this possible with plotly-python? Can someone help please?

Comment: See if this gives you what you're looking for: `fig.update_yaxes(rangemode = 'tozero')`

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, the plot remains the same.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. It's always best to provide a reproducible question since the data you're using has a huge impact on what happens. For now, could you tell me the literal ranges of each y-axis? (Greatest value - lowest value for each side)

Comment: I have updated the code above indicating how the dataset is created. For col 1 the min is -6 and the max is 111, and for col 2 the min is -787.5 and the max is 25682. Does this help?

Comment: Definitely...adding your data to your answer is even better...you did just add it right? I'm not losing my mind and it was there all along...hmm, looking at it now.

Comment: No worries, I've just added the data. Happy to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because plotly calculates the default yaxis ranges under the hood using the following: `[y_min-padding, y_max+padding]` where `padding=(y_max-y_min)/16`.

Generally this will mean the zeros for `yaxis1` and `yaxis2` won't necessarily align (and most likely won't). However, we can solve for the padding of the yaxis2 by figuring out the relative location of the 0 on yaxis1. For example:

```
y1_min, y1_max = df_overview['col 2'].min(), df_overview['col 2'].max()
y1_padding = (y1_max - y1_min)/16
y1_range = [y1_min - y1_padding, y1_max + y1_padding]
y1_relative_zero = (0 - y1_range[0]) / (y1_range[1] - y1_range[0])
```

`y1_relative_zero = 0.08200108720519005` meaning that the 0 on the y1 axis is roughly 8.2% of the way between the min and max. Now we can solve for the necessary padding on the second yaxis to ensure the 0 is also the same percent of the way between the min and max of the y2 data.

We need the solution to the following equation:

```
(0 - y2_range_min) / (y2_range_max - y2_range_min) = y1_relative_zero
```

where `y2_range_min = y2_min - y2_padding` and `y2_range_max = y2_max + y2_padding`.

I won't go into all the details since it's rearranging variables, but this is the solution:

```
y2_padding = (y1_relative_zero * (y2_max - y2_min) + y2_min) / (1 - 2*y1_relative_zero)
```

Putting this all together:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {'col 1': [-6, 18.6, 106.35, 111],
        'col 2': [-787.5, 976.5, 11246, 25682]}
df_overview = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_overview.index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
colors = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF']  # red, blue
columns = ['col 1', 'col 2']
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=df_overview.index, y=df_overview[col], name=col, marker_color=colors[i], offsetgroup=i,),
        secondary_y=(i == 0)
    )
fig.update_layout(
    barmode='group',
    font_size=14,
    hovermode="x unified",
)

y1_min, y1_max = df_overview['col 2'].min(), df_overview['col 2'].max()
y1_padding = (y1_max - y1_min)/16
y1_range = [y1_min - y1_padding, y1_max + y1_padding]
y1_relative_zero = (0 - y1_range[0]) / (y1_range[1] - y1_range[0])

y2_min, y2_max = df_overview['col 1'].min(), df_overview['col 1'].max()

## we solve the following equation:
# (0 - y2_range_min) / (y2_range_max - y2_range_min) = y1_relative_zero
# (0 - (y2_min - y2_padding)) / ((y2_max - y2_min) + 2*y2_padding) = y1_relative_zero
# y1_relative_zero * ((y2_max - y2_min) + 2*y2_padding) = (y2_padding - y2_min)
# y1_relative_zero * (y2_max - y2_min) + (y1_relative_zero*2*y2_padding) = (y2_padding - y2_min)
# (y2_padding - y2_min) - (y1_relative_zero*2*y2_padding) = y1_relative_zero * (y2_max - y2_min)
# y2_padding(1 - 2*y1_relative_zero) - y2_min = y1_relative_zero * (y2_max - y2_min)
y2_padding = (y1_relative_zero * (y2_max - y2_min) + y2_min) / (1 - 2*y1_relative_zero)
y2_range = [y2_min - y2_padding, y2_max + y2_padding]

fig.update_yaxes(range=y1_range, secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(range=y2_range, secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a very thorough and , I think, a universal solution to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've got several answers now, but I worked it out my own way and thought I would still throw in my 2 cents.

In this modification, I added `yaxis2` to your `fig.update_layout`, using the above zero values to set the scale ratio between the y-axes. I then set the range to align their zeros.

Check it out.

```
fig.update_layout(
    barmode='group',
    font_size=14,
    hovermode="x unified",
    yaxis2 = dict(scaleanchor = "y", scaleratio = 25682/111, range = [-7.25, 115])
)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a simple solution. I see that you basically added: `scaleratio = df_overview['col 2'].max()/df_overview['col 1'].max()` to the layout function, right? Where is the `range = [-7.25, 115]` coming from?

Comment: Comment out the range & the zero for `yaxis2` is lower than `yaxis`. We needed the ratio below zero to be the same as above zero. That means you need less padding on the bottom of `yaxis2`. While I set it to `-7.25, 115`, Plotly adjusts to maintain that `scaleratio`. So it's a bit of a guess (the math is lengthy and unnecessary). You can see the actual ranges with `ff = fig.full_figure_for_development(); print(ff.layout.yaxis.range, ff.layout.yaxis2.range)`. Do this without then with the `range`, the ratio *below 0* goes from about 207 to 233 (25682/111 is about 233). Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. Thank you very much for the explanation.